# How to select in mysql the ratio between the count of records and the count of records with same value of a field?

Tags: mysql, select

Let's say I have a table in a mysql database

```
(id,idWord,isCorrect)
------------------
('1','1', '0'),
('2','1', '1'),
('3','1', '1'),
('4','1', '1'),
('5','1', '0'),
('6','1', '1'),

('7','2', '0'),
('8','2', '0'),
('9','2', '1'),
('10','2', '1')
```

How may I select the ratio between the count of records having isCorrect=1 and the total count of records with same idWord?  in this case would result in

```
('1','0.6')     (-> 4/6)
('2','0.5')     (-> 2/4)
```

I tried

```
 SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(`isCorrect`) FROM `wordstyped` GROUP BY `idWord`,`isCorrect`) 
  / 
  (SELECT COUNT(`isCorrect`) FROM `wordstyped` GROUP BY `idWord`,`isCorrect` WHERE `isCorrect`=1)
```

but it doesn't work.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f36c58/1

Comment: `('1','0.5')     (-> 3/6)` should be `('1','0.5')     (-> 4/6)` instead?

Comment: Three out of six? Eh?

Comment: yep, sorry, corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `SELECT` as a value, it has to return just one row, you can't return all the grouped rows. You can do it with a single query that sums multiple things.

```
SELECT idWord, SUM(isCorrect = 1) / COUNT(*) AS ratio
FROM `wordstyped`
GROUP BY idWord
```

A comparison expression like `isCorrect = 1` evaluates to `1` when it's true, `0` when false, so summing them counts the number of rows where the condition is true.

You can also use the `AVG()` function, since an average is just a total divided by the count.

```
SELECT idWord, AVG(isCorrect = 1) AS ratio
FROM `wordstyped`
GROUP BY idWord
```

Comment: You forgot to include the **FROM** clause, :-)

Comment: yep SELECT `idWord`, AVG(`isCorrect` = 1) AS `ratio` FROM `wordstyped` GROUP BY `idWord` is doing the trick :)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was trying to explain why *his* query didn't work, since he didn't combine everything into a single row. Using `GROUP_CONCAT` would merge everything into a single row.

Comment: How do you know the topicstarter is even male? Sasha is a female and male name.. But you are right i don't even know why i even made that comment about GROUP_CONCAT but must because it's late over here so i guess i will remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
    idWord,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isCorrect = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS corrects,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isCorrect = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS ratio
FROM
    wordstyped
GROUP BY
    idWord
```

Comment: In MySQL you can simply do `SUM(isCorrect = 1)` which is the same as `SUM(CASE WHEN isCorrect = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Yeah, i'm not too familiarized with that simplification still, anyways, using AVG as @Barmar shows, is the best way for this case.